# delete multiple rows with same value in sql 14

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns and the first column is 'name'. Some names are entered twice, some 3 times and some more than that. I would like to keep only one value for each name and delete the extra rows.
There are no primary keys or id column.
There are about 1 million rows in the table.
Would like to delete using one query(preferably) in SQL 14. Can someone help please?

```
Name    column2 column3
Suzy        
Suzy        
Suzy        
John        
John        
George      
George      
George      
George
```

Would like to have it as:

```
Name    column2 column3
Suzy        
John        
George
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number function, try like this,

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME
            )
    FROM < YourTableName >
    )
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```